# Why is the variable undefined?

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, undefined

Here is my code

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var options = {
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Money Conversion'
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Exchange Rate'
            }
        },
        xAxis: {
            type: 'datetime',
            dateTimeLabelFormat: {
            }
        },
        series: [{
            type: 'line',
            data: []
        }]
    };

    $(document).ready(function () {

        if (typeof options != 'undefined') {
            alert("options is undefined!");
        }
        else {
            alert("options is defined!");
        }
```

The alert I am getting is "options is undefined". What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Wow thank you everyone! I can't believe I missed that...

Comment: +1 (offsetting) I don't understand why this has been downvoted. It illustrates a common oversight I've made many times myself.

Comment: @Bob Kaufman: This is really an example of a problem you can easily analyze yourself. Namely by checking why the `if` clause is passing - the reason cannot be anything else - and the answer is right there... "not undefined"

Comment: @pimvdb I think we've all been in the situation where we've been looking at the same piece of code for too long to think straight.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
    if (typeof options != 'undefined') {
        alert("options is undefined!");
    }
```

You're alerting 'options is undefined' when options **is** defined.

Comment: `+1` ha LOL. that's a big gaff  ^_^

Answer (score 5):

You're testing it for unequality. Use == instead :)

Answer (score 5):

```
if (typeof options != 'undefined') {
```

means options is defined

```
if (typeof options == 'undefined') {
```

Answer (score 5):

Haven't you got your operators the wrong way around?  Shouldn't it be as follows?

```
    if (typeof options == 'undefined') {
        alert("options is undefined!");
    }
    else {
        alert("options is defined!");
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

        if (typeof options === 'undefined') {
            alert("options is undefined!");
        }
        else {
            alert("options is defined!");
        }
```

Answer (score 4):

Because of the `!=` operator? Perhaps change that to `==`? Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Your operator on the if statement is incorrect. Should be:

```
if (typeof options == 'undefined') 
{        
    alert("options is undefined!");     
}    
else 
{         
    alert("options is defined!");     
}
```